# Changing Android app's status bar color but keep translucency

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

For an app I'm building, I used the [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).
I created an app that uses a `TabLayout`. A little feature of the app is that when the user changes tabs, the color of both the `TabLayout` and the `Toolbar` change to a corresponding color. We're also using the new `NavigationView`, to present the user with a Material design `DrawerLayout`.

However, changing the color of both the `TabLayout` and the `Toolbar` is no problem at all, we do it in the lines of the following;

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor)));
getBaseActivity().getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor)));
mTabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(primaryColor));
```

This is all good, and working like it's supposed to. The problem appears when I try to set the `Status bar` background. Since the material design specification tells us that the `NavigationDrawer` should get some special treatment, below image shows how the status bar is actually a form of translucent. The Navigation Drawer falls over my main fragment while the navigation bar is above both, being a translucent bar.

[image: What it should look like]

My first thoughts were that it's just a bar with a #7000 hexadecimal value or something, but I couldn't be further from the truth. Doing that doesn't change the color of the actual color it should "darken".

After that I just tried setting the darker version of the required color as the background for the status bar like so;

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getBaseActivity().getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
}
```

But after doing this, the complete functionality breaks. My view will look like this:

[image]

In essence, what can I do to fix this behaviour? I'd really like to change it so that the translucency feature still does what it needs to do according to the Material design spec, but also change the `status bar`'s background color.

Comment: doesn't specifying the color with alpha work? like instead of plain red #FF0000  change it to #34FF0000   where 34 is the alpha value ... `window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_alpha_statusbar_color));`

Comment: This works, however the color that results from me trying to find the exact same color is always different and rather ugly. I'd rather let Android do it's algorithm on the color when I set it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is always a translucent shadow behind it and you can not remove it. So you can try to play around with your colors alpha channel to achieve an acceptable result or think about a workaround solution like this:
As far as I see you just want that the status bar color is slightly different  when the navigation drawer is open, right? So why not adding just a empty `View` with the desired color and the same height as statusbar  in your NavigationDrawer layout to achieve the same effect?

Btw, there is a `R.dimen.status_bar_height` height specification.

Comment: What I really want is the same result I get when setting a color in the `styles.xml`. Because, if I do that, the status bar automatically get's a certain shaded colour that seems to work with the navigation drawer. If I change the color programatically, the functionality breaks. I found that setting a color with an alpha channel works, but it's not as pretty as the native functionality. I'd rather fake that functionality or do it as good as the OS does it itself.

Answer (score 0):

Activity layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include layout="@layout/drawerlayout_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Activty theme, set statusBarColor to transparent

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

NavigationView extends ScrimInsetsFrameLayout, it will draw some color at the statusbar position

[image]